# Is it possible to have a program that changes the keyboard input to all other programs?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, textfield

Is it possible to make a program that runs in the background and after a certain combination of keys is pressed it inserts certain characters?

For example could a program make it so that any time (anywhere) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> is pressed the phrase "Copyright 2012" is inserted?

Comment: Autohotkey is something along the lines of `::^m::copyright 2012`. If you can use that, save yourself the trouble.

Comment: It certainly is possible (as autohotkey shows). It's not neccessary to write, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Technically this would answer your question already, but I'll give you the function do to so as well: [RegisterHotkey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Don't forget `SendInput` :) `RegisterHotKey` will also fail if another hotkey is set up for ctrl-m, in which case a hook might be a better option.